# Splitting a line with special character

Tags: python

I have a line which looks like this:

```
line ='timing                 [dash<try></example><try>x</trial>]           -122    µm'
```

I want to extract the -122 value.This is what I have written:

```
a = line.split("]")
b = a[1].split("x")
c= b[0].split("µm")
my_val = float(c[0].replace(" ", ""))
```

The "µ" seems to cause a problem here. And above code shows error if I compile it. Is there any idea to work with those special characters?

Small Edit:

I am reading the "line" from some file. I am using python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Python + Unicode tutorial. At first if you have any unicode characters use u e.g. It is safe to use u' ... ' for every string in your code.

```
line = u'timing....'
c= b[0].split(u"µm")
```

Comment: Please see the edit above. I am reading the line from a file.

Comment: So use codecs package to read it and still use u'...' everywhere

Comment: Sorry I have created another post for file encoding problem. I am already using codecs.open(... My source file format is utf-16-le. from thsi file I am trying to split the line and µ like I mentioned. How do I use encoding in my code ?

Comment: Python unicode is encoding unaware. If you correctly read file as unicode and you put u".." on every string it should work just like with ascii.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine in python 2.7

```
>>> line ='timing                 [dash<try></example><try>x</trial>]           -122    µm'
>>> a = line.split("]")
>>> b = a[1].split("x")
>>> c= b[0].split("µm")
>>> a
['timing                 [dash<try></example><try>x</trial>', '           -122    \xc2\xb5m']
>>> b
['           -122    \xc2\xb5m']
>>> c
['           -122    ', '']
>>> c[0].replace(" ", "")
'-122'
>>> c[0].strip()
'-122'
>>> float(c[0].replace(" ", ""))
-122.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran your code in Python 3.3.

```
print(my_val)
```

prints -122.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

line ="asdfasd;l  lakfdalskd -122 asfdsd"
print re.findall(r'-\d+', line)
```